# How to have GROUP BY and COUNT include zero sums?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have SQL like this (where `$ytoday` is 5 days ago):

```
$sql = 'SELECT Count(*), created_at FROM People WHERE created_at >= "'. $ytoday .'" AND GROUP BY DATE(created_at)';
```

I want this to return a value for every day, so it would return 5 results in this case (5 days ago until today).

But say `Count(*)` is 0 for yesterday, instead of returning a zero it doesn't return any data at all for that date.

How can I change that SQLite query so it also returns data that has a count of 0?

Comment: Select all the rows you want first, then run a count on these rows (left join perhaps)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Without convoluted (in my opinion) queries, your output data-set won't include dates that don't exist in your input data-set.  This means that you need a data-set with the 5 days to join on to.

The simple version would be to create a table with the 5 dates, and join on that.  I typically create and keep *(effectively caching)* a calendar table with every date I could ever need.  *(Such as from 1900-01-01 to 2099-12-31.)*

```
SELECT
  calendar.calendar_date,
  Count(People.created_at)
FROM
  Calendar
LEFT JOIN
  People
    ON Calendar.calendar_date = People.created_at
WHERE
  Calendar.calendar_date >= '2012-05-01'
GROUP BY
  Calendar.calendar_date
```

Comment: Hmm, seems simple enough. This is always the last 5 days though, so a static table wouldn't work. Thoughts?

Comment: @JBurace - A static table does work. You just change your WHERE clause. For example, mine shows "every date since `'2012-05-01'`" because I'm lazy and didn't specify a 5 day range in that WHERE clause.  Then you do as you already are and build that WHERE clause to suit your needs.

Comment: Hmm okay. I thought `create a table with the 5 dates` meant create a table with only 5 entries.

Comment: @JBurace - `I typically create and keep (effectively caching) a calendar table with every date I could ever need. (Such as from 1900-01-01 to 2099-12-31.)`

Answer (score 5):

You'll need to left join against a list of dates. You can either create a table with the dates you need in it, or you can take the dynamic approach I outlined here:

[generate days from date range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157282/generate-days-from-date-range/2157776#2157776)