# Replacing no rows with 0 value

Tags: sql-server

I have the below query

```
SELECT    DATEPART(YEAR, Date_Reported) AS 'Year',
          DATEPART(MONTH, Date_Reported) AS 'Month',
          DATEPART(DAY, Date_Reported) AS 'Day',
          COUNT(*) AS 'Transactions'
FROM TX
WHERE Date_Reported >= DATEADD(day,-7, GETDATE())
GROUP BY  DATEPART(DAY, Date_Reported),
          DATEPART(MONTH, Date_Reported),
          DATEPART(YEAR, Date_Reported)
ORDER BY  'Year',
          'Month',
          'Day'
```

What it gives me is the last 7 days of transactions, but when a days transaction is 0 it does not show a row. What I would like is for the no rows to be displayed as a 0 value under the transaction column like below:

```
YEAR | MONTH | DAY | TRANSACTIONS
2018 | 9     | 4   |     2
2018 | 9     | 5   |     2
2018 | 9     | 6   |     0
2018 | 9     | 7   |     5
2018 | 9     | 8   |     2
2018 | 9     | 9   |     0
2018 | 9     | 10  |     0
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Count to include zero values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12372708/sql-count-to-include-zero-values)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to have GROUP BY and COUNT include zero sums?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10586746/how-to-have-group-by-and-count-include-zero-sums)

Comment: Only thing I would add to Tanner's link is instead use a tally table, rather than an rCTE.

Comment: Maybe comparing to `DATEADD(day,-7, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))` would be more accurate if you want the count for the oldest date not to depend on the time you run the query.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible solution:

```
WITH LastDays AS --Base table
(
  SELECT CAST(DATEADD(DAY,-D,SYSDATETIME()) AS Date) D FROM (VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6)) T(D)
), TX AS --Demo data
(
  SELECT * FROM (VALUES
  (CAST(SYSDATETIME() AS Date)),
  (CAST(DATEADD(DAY,-2,SYSDATETIME()) AS Date))
  ) T(Date_Reported)
)
SELECT    DATEPART(YEAR, D) AS 'Year',
          DATEPART(MONTH, D) AS 'Month',
          DATEPART(DAY, D) AS 'Day',
          COUNT(Date_Reported) AS 'Transactions'
FROM LastDays
LEFT JOIN TX ON Date_Reported=D
GROUP BY  DATEPART(DAY, D),
          DATEPART(MONTH, D),
          DATEPART(YEAR, D)
ORDER BY  'Year',
          'Month',
          'Day'
```

Comment: hi thanks, is this query dynamic as i cna see the demo data being used? Basically will this work without me having to manually edit demo datta

Comment: I don't have TX table so I have to simulate it. You can omit this section and use real table. Also make sure `Date`data type is used (not `DateTime`, `DateTime2`) to ignore hours, minutes and seconds in comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

Here is Solution,

First You have to create Date Table as base Table Because of You don't have some date Records in `TX` as you have displayed as 0.
As per below Query You can Create that Table and Store it into Temp Table.

```
;WITH cte AS (
SELECT cast(GETDATE() as date) AS myDate
UNION ALL
SELECT cast( DATEADD(DAY,-1,myDate) as date)
FROM cte
where myDate >= DATEADD(day,-7, GETDATE())
)
SELECT myDate Into #dateTable
FROM cte
```

Second, You can use Left Join `#dateTable` and Your `TX` as per Shown below.

```
select DATEPART(YEAR, myDate) AS 'Year',
       DATEPART(MONTH, myDate) AS 'Month',
       DATEPART(DAY, myDate) AS 'Day',
       Count(Date_Reported) as 'Transactions'
from #dateTable
LEFT JOIN #Tempdata on CAST(Date_Reported as DATE) = CASt(myDate as date)
GROUP BY  DATEPART(DAY, myDate),
          DATEPART(MONTH, myDate),
          DATEPART(YEAR, myDate)
ORDER BY  'Year',
          'Month',
          'Day'
```